# How to print data accurately to a file in Matlab using fopen function

Tags: matlab

I have a Matrix REF in Matlab as shown.

```
REF=[0 1;
     1 1;
     2 1;
     5 10;
    10 0;
    50 1;
   100 2;
  1000 1];
```

When I save REF to a file by using  the following code.

```
A1=REF(:,1);
A2=REF(:,2);
fileID = fopen('exp.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%d %d\n', A1, A2);
fclose(fileID);
```

The output is not as desired. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: "The output is not as desired". Do you get  really nice oil painting of a velocirraptor?  Sorry for the irony, but why do you not get what you wanted?

Comment: The output should be the matrix REF in the same order. But it is being printed in wrong order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `dlmwrite` and `dlmread` for writing/reading matrix to/from file.

http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html

```
M =

   25.1327    3.1416   18.8496
    9.4248   15.7080   21.9911
   12.5664   28.2743    6.2832

dlmwrite('myFile.txt',M,'delimiter','\t','precision',3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If, for some reason, you prefer to go with `fprintf` (because you need to write more things after each line for example) there is no worry in looping here:

```
fileID = fopen('exp.txt','w');
for ii=1:size(REF,1)
    fprintf(fileID,'%d %d\n', REF(ii,1),REF(ii,2));
end
fclose(fileID);
```

Answer (score 0):

`fprintf` writes data according to column order, so in your case you could just transpose `REF` to get the correct output. So in your `fprintf` call:

```
fprintf(fileID,'%d %d\n', REF.');
```

Comment: I didn't find anywhere in the documentation this issue of writing in the column order, but I am struggling with it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `w` to `wt` and take transpose of `REF` as done below:-

```
fileID = fopen('exp.txt','wt');
fprintf(fileID,'%d %d \n', REF.');
fclose(fileID);
```